# Why cannot join the processes after the work is done?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a `Queue`, a `Manager` and a `Lock` inside a class. The class has a run function that starts 6 `Process` and they all wait to an exit_flag to be true in order to end their jobs. However, I cannot "end" the jobs because when I call the join methods on each job, it blocks it. The code looks as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Queue, Manager


class MyClass():
     def __init__(self):
          self.q = Queue(maxsize=50)
          self.lock = Lock()
          manager = Manager()
          self.manager = manager.dict()

     def fill_queue(self,idx):
          while not self.exit():
               #do something
               result,result_type= self.perform_extraction()
               if result_type not in self.manager():
                    self.manager[result_type] = []
               while self.q.full() and not self.exit():
                    sleep(10)
               if self.exit():
                    print('Exit filler')
                    break
               self.lock.acquire()
               self.q.put((result,result_type))
               self.lock.release()
          else:
               print(f'queue filler {idx} ended')

     def empty_queue(self,idx):
          while not self.exit():
               if self.q.emtpy():
                    continue
               self.lock.aquire()
               result, result_type = self.q.get()
               self.lock.release()
               result,id = self.perform_test(queue_value)
               if result >=0 and result not in self.manager[result_type]:
                    self.manager[id] += [(result, result_type)]
               self.insert_to_database(result, result_type) --> this inserts the value into a sqlite3 ddbb
          else:
               print(f'worker {idx} ended')


     def run(self,n_workers):
          jobs = []
          for _ in range(2):
               p = Process(target = self.fill_queue, args=(_,))
               jobs.append(p)

          for _ in range(n_workers):
               p = Process(target = self.empty_queue, args=(_,))
               jobs.append(p)

          for job in jobs:
               job.start()

          for idx,job in enumerate(jobs):
               print(f'joining job {idx}')
               job.join()
               if not job.is_alive():
                    print(f'closing job {idx}')
                    job.close()
               else:
                    print(f'job {idx} still alive')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     mc = MyClass()
     mc.run(n_workers = 4)
     print('RUN ENDED!')
```

The `manager` is used to communicate between processes and when the criteria is met and I have X amount of elements in the `manager`, the `self.exit()` function returns `True`.

When I run this code, it gets stucked printing `joining job 0` and it stays there forever, I dont know why. If I add some timeout and set it to `job.join(5)` (5 arbitary, no real reason), it prints:

```
joining job 0
job 0 still alive
joining job 1
job 1 still alive
joining job 2
closing job 2
joining job 3
closing job 3
joining job 4
closing job 4
joining job 5
closing job 5
RUN ENDED!
```

And the code does not finish. I also tried to do `job.terminate()` if the job is still alive and this throwed an error telling me that some leaked folders could not be found. Does this means that I have some zombie processes?

Why this is happening? What I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**: Added some logic on the interaction with `manager()`. I'm using the manager to add a couple of types of results and append all results of same type to a list, so the dict structure is something like `{result_type:[result_values]}` and the reason to use manager is to avoid storing duplicate results and check when I the algorithm mets the exit criteria.

Now, the exit criteria function looks like this:

```
def exit(self):
     for v in self.manager.values():
          if len(v) < 10:
               return False
     return True
```

So, all processes ends when I have 10 items on each list of each type. There are 3 possible amount of different types, so once each type is added as a manager key, it only needs to be filled and when all 3 have at least 10 values (there could be more), then all the job should end.

---

EDIT 2: Added some printing information to `fill_queue` and `empty_queue` functions. What is printed is:

worker 0 ended
worker 1 ended
queue filler 0 ended
worker 2 ended
queue filler 1 ended
joining job 0 --> *
worker 3 ended

- so this usually (like always) prints before all workers print the "ended" statement, but it never joins the first job. This is actually stuck at the first try of calling `join` method at the `for idx,job in enumerate(jobs):` cycle.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the `exit()` method is defined?  You've said it relates to the `manager`, however nothing in your code interacts with the manager.  You code is likely stuck in an infinite loop (`while not self.exit()` being the most likely culprit) so it's tricky to diagnose without knowing when `exit()` will return true.

Comment: @SimonBowly Hi! Added `manager` interactions and the `exit` function. The exit function is inside the class.

Comment: Sorry @xerac, it's not really possible to help here without a complete working example.  Elements placed in the manager are handled by your methods `perform_extraction` and `perform_test` which are missing.  If I add basic implementations of these functions I can't reproduce your issue so there's clearly something important in the logic there.  Can you try to reduce your example to a single piece of code which runs on its own and reproduces the behaviour you're describing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SimonBowly. I didn't post those functions because I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible in order to explain the issue I am experiencing and, as far as I understand, those functions should not interfere with the process itself. The functions don't use any `multiprocessing` component. It could be a `np.random.randint()` function and the `result_type` types could be `odd` and `even`. Functions like those shouldn't affect the code, right? Now, I can add those functions, but could you explain why these could be an issue if they are not ussing any `mp` component?

Comment: The reason I ask is that, from what you've described, your code is stuck waiting at job.join() for job 0 to finish.  Since job 0 is running 'fill_queue', my best guess is that this function is stuck waiting for self.exit() to be true, which depends on the logic in the functions you have not included.  For example if I set both these functions to `return 1, 'a'` the code exists normally.  I suggest adding some logging which prints the state of the manager to the sleep loop in fill_queue to help diagnose this.

Comment: *exits normally

Comment: Thanks @SimonBowly, I got it now. I ran a couple of tests adding some printing information to see if the process that fills the queue get actually out of the loop and added what I found to the main question. I'm still not able to get to know why the `join` can't be performed, despite the fact that the `while` loop actually ends :(

Comment: Something I forgot to mention, but maybe its important to, I'm running this on Windows 8 (for now, at least)